# vercel: how to deploy project via cli with project name as paremeter

Tags: vercel

I wish to deploy project with project name set via vercel cli.

How it works now:
Pretend that I have app `myproject` in Vercel cloud.
Pretend that localy I have folder `superproject`, and inside it I run:

```
npx vercel deploy --prod --yes
```

Vercel creates/override app with name matching `parent folder` where command is run. So my app is named `superproject.vercel.app`

How to change this command to deploy to exact project i.e. `myproject` and ignore parent folder name, like:

```
npx vercel deploy --prod --yes myproject
```

UPDATE:

Tried:

```
npx vercel deploy --name myproject --prod --yes
```

But deploy still pointing to parent folder name + produce warning:

```
❗️  The "--name" option is deprecated (https://vercel.link/name-flag)
```